# can't find out how to create a css selector for yahoo stocks page

Tags: css, jsoup

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&ql=0

I am trying to get the number right under the title with the symbol. I know the xpath is  xpath `//div[@class='title']/following::span[2]/text()` but I am using Jsoup and trying to learn css selectors. I have tried a number of things none of which even returned any values.

I am trying things like `div.title div > span > span`

Comment: so you're trying to get the value of the stock? The number right under where it says "Apple Inc (APPL)"?

Comment: yes I need the integer value to compare before and after, I got this to work p > span:nth-child(1), but I feel this isn't safe for dynamic pages is it? I want a fail safe css selector where I don't have to worry about if elements are added to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems that you want to retrieve the value of the span which is child to the span with id `time_rtq_ticker`, so use this selector:

```
#time_rtq_ticker>span
```

that will retrieve the element

Comment: thanks I see there are a number of ways to do it, what is considered best practice?

Comment: I would guess that the element has the same id on all pages, do I think this one would work the best. There isn't really a "best practice", i think